# CampaignMemberStatus records only testable with seeAllData flag?

Tags: trigger, campaign

I wrote a trigger that creates some CampaignMemberStatus records against a Campaign automatically, and noticed that when I tried to test my logic any queries that I run for CampaignMemberStatus against Campaigns in a unit test seem to return empty collections unless I turn on seeAllData. Is there a reason for this that I am missing?

I'm essentially running this query and returning results (which are empty without seeAllData). I played with the runAs user being some different profiles as well.

```
SELECT Label, CampaignId FROM CampaignMemberStatus WHERE CampaignId =: c.Id
```

**EDIT:** Added simple unit test that fails just trying to run a query. When I execute this with seeAllData enabled it works, and when I run actual code it works fine (the two default Status values, Sent and Responded, always show up when you query for a new Campaign's CampaignMemberStatus children).

```
Profile p = [Select Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Std Access'];

User user1 = new User(FirstName = 'Test', 
              Username = 'test1@test434.com', 
              LastName = 'User 1', 
              Email = 'test1@test.com', 
              Alias = 'test1', 
              CommunityNickname = 'test1', 
              EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8', 
              LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
              LocalesIdKey = 'en_US', 
              TimeZonesIdKey = 'America/Los_Angeles', 
              ProfileId = p.Id,
              UserPermissionsMarketingUser = true);
insert user1;

System.runAs(user1)
{
    Campaign c = new Campaign();
    c.Name = 'Test Campaign';
    insert c;

    List<Campaign> campaigns = new List<Campaign>();
    campaigns.add(c);

    Map<String, Set<String>> existingStatus = CampaignTriggerUtil.getExistingCampaignMemberStatusLabelsMap(new List<Campaign>(campaigns));

    System.assertEquals(1, existingStatus.size());
}
```

In this case, the implementation of that custom method is below (simple enough I think):

```
public static Map<String, Set<String>> getExistingCampaignMemberStatusLabelsMap(List<Campaign> campaigns)
{
    Map<String, Set<String>> existingStatus = new Map<String, Set<String>>();
    for (CampaignMemberStatus status : [SELECT Label, CampaignId FROM CampaignMemberStatus WHERE CampaignId =: campaigns])
    {
        Set<String> tempSet = new Set<String>();
        if (existingStatus.containsKey(status.CampaignId))
        {
            tempSet = existingStatus.get(status.CampaignId);
        }

        tempSet.add(status.Label);
        existingStatus.put(status.CampaignId, tempSet);
    }
    return existingStatus;
}
```

Comment: Was the `runAs` user enabled as a marketing user?

Comment: There is an example in [CampaignMember: Status in Trigger Unit Test <> UI behaviour](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/CampaignMember-Status-in-Trigger-Unit-Test-lt-gt-UI-behaviour/m-p/163918#M24548) that shows inserting test  CampaignMemberStatus records. Are you setting the `SortOrder ` field? Maybe add your test code to the question.

Comment: Also, if you're not inserting the campaignmemberstatus before you query, you obviously wouldn't see the value without seealldata; that's the point of that feature.

Comment: Yes, I did set the runAs user as a marketing user. I am also setting the SortOrder. I will add a simple unit test I wrote

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To answer your question, yes, the CampaignMemberStatus records automatically created on insert of a Campaign are invisible to test methods annotated with @isTest(seeAllData=false).

I don't believe that you are doing anything wrong, and I have attempted to report this as a defect to salesforce a few times through H&T Cases, but have never managed to get it to be listed as a known issue.

I believe the CampaignMemberStatus records should be visible within the test class, as they are effectively created in the background by salesforce after inserting the Campaign record. If I wrote a trigger to create linked records to the Campaign they would be visible in the test class.

Here's an example of a test class to demonstrate the issue.

```
public with sharing class TEST_CampaignMemberStatus { 

    @isTest(seeAllData=true) 
    static void passing() { 
        Campaign c = new Campaign(Name = 'a'); 
        insert c; 

        List <CampaignMemberStatus> cmStatus = [SELECT id, CampaignID, HasResponded, IsDefault, Label, SortOrder 
                                                  FROM CampaignMemberStatus 
                                                 WHERE CampaignId = :c.Id]; 
        //expect two records 
        System.assertEquals(2,cmStatus.size()); 
    } 

    @isTest(seeAllData=false) 
    static void failing() { 
        Campaign c = new Campaign(Name = 'a'); 
        insert c; 
        List <CampaignMemberStatus> cmStatus = [SELECT id, CampaignID, HasResponded, IsDefault, Label, SortOrder 
                                                  FROM CampaignMemberStatus 
                                                 WHERE CampaignId = :c.Id]; 

        //should be 2 but is 0
        System.assertEquals(2,cmStatus.size()); 
    } 
}
```

On top of this, the invisible records still cause unique key violations in the seeAllData=false test method if they attempt to insert a status with the sort order 1 or 2, as the test causes the cryptic error message:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []
```

At the moment the options to avoid this are

1. Ensuring all tests of code that interact with the CampaignMemberStatus object run with seeAllData=true
2. Hard coding any interactions with the CampaignMemberStatus to expect the two records that salesforce creates as standard.

Both are undesirable, for example if you have written a trigger on the Campaign object, your trigger cannot know if the CampaignMemberStatus records will be present or not when it executes.
Hard coding any logic to expect the standard 2 CampaignMemberStatus records is undesirable due to the risk that if salesforce were to change the default statuses or introduce functionality for users to customise statuses then code may break.